# Doctrine 2 gives 500 Error on simple query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this doctrine query:

```
$attributeQuery = $em->createQuery("SELECT PARTIAL p.{id} FROM m:Product p JOIN m:BtgNode n WITH n.attribute = p.amazonCatUs1 WHERE n.id = :node")->setMaxResults(5);
$attributeQuery->setParameter('node', $amazonCategoryId);
$products = $attributeQuery->getResult();
```

Which causes a 500 error. When I comment out the getResult line, the page finishes loading, and when I run `$attributeQuery->getSql()` and execute the result though phpmyadmin the result return correctly in less than 0.001 seconds.

I cannot find anything at all to explain this behavior.

The full script:

```
$em = $app['orm.em'];
        echo ini_get('memory_limit').'<br>';

        ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', -1);
        ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', -1);

        $productQuery = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM m:Product p WHERE p.amazonUsBrowse1 = :node OR p.amazonUsBrowse2 = :node");
        $productQuery->setParameter('node', $amazonCategoryId);
        $productQuery->useQueryCache(false);

        //if results, then not clothing and simple, else complicated
        $products = $productQuery->getResult();
        print memory_get_usage(true);
        if (count($products) == 0) {
            $em->clear();
            echo 'complex';

            $attributeQuery = $em->createQuery("SELECT PARTIAL p.{id} FROM m:Product p JOIN m:BtgNode n WITH n.attribute = p.amazonCatUs1 WHERE n.id = :node")->setMaxResults(5);
            $attributeQuery->setParameter('node', $amazonCategoryId);
            //$attributeQuery->useQueryCache(false);
            var_dump($attributeQuery->getSql());

            $products = $attributeQuery->getResult();
            var_dump($attributeQuery->getSql());
        }
        var_dump($products);
        die();
```

Comment: I added $products = $attributeQuery->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR); Which got it working at a reasonable pace again - although I don't think it addressed the underlying casue (what that is).

Comment: A 500 error doesn't tell you much.  Have a look in the app/logs/dev file when the error occurs and it should give you a more detailed explanation. Or if you are in the production environment look in app/logs/prod.